# Debug Celery pending task

Tags: python, flask, celery

I have a web app built with Flask, Gunicorn, Celery, Redis and RabbitMQ.
The system can manage thousands of tasks every day, but sometimes one task stay in a pending state forever.

Also in my logs I see that there is an exception in the following piece of code:

```
def taskstatus(task_id):
task = collect_task.AsyncResult(task_id)
if task.state == 'PENDING':
    # job did not start yet
    response = {
        'state': task.state,
        'current': 0,
        'total': 1,
        'status': 'Pending...'
    }
elif task.state != 'FAILURE':
    response = {
        'state': task.state,
        'current': task.info.get('current', 0), #<<This line generate and exception
        'total': task.info.get('total', 1),
        'status': task.info.get('status', '')
    }
    if 'result' in task.info:
        response['result'] = task.info['result']
else:
    # something went wrong in the background job
    response = {
        'state': task.state,
        'current': 1,
        'total': 1,
        'status': str(task.info),  # this is the exception raised
    }
return jsonify(response)
```

The exception is: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`

So, as far as I understand the task briefly transition from `PENDING` to another state so it enter the second `if` but than the `info` attribute is `None` so an error is raised.

How can I solve this or at least get more information on why the task stay in a `PENDING` state forever?